# Accesing a cell inside a unbutton action causing crash swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
@IBAction func selectInviteBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

 let cell = matchedUsersTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as! MultiUserTableViewCell

if selectedUsers[sender.tag] == nil{
    selectedUsers[sender.tag] = true
}else if selectedUsers[sender.tag] == false{
    selectedUsers[sender.tag] = true
}else{
    selectedUsers[sender.tag] = false
}
var count = 0
for value in selectedUsers.values{
    if value{
        count += 1
    }
}
if count == (currentUserRide as! RiderRide).availableSeats + 1{
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeToast(message: Strings.passengers_more_than_available, duration: 5.0, position: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height-300))
}  

  setSelectButtonBasedOnSelection(isSelected:selectedUsers[sender.tag],button: cell.matchedUserSelectBtn)
}
```

I am clicking on button before tableview is loaded so that crash is happening any solution for it?

Comment: If you are saying that you click button before table loads, it can be assumed that button is not a part of table. Are you changing the button(sender) tag somewhere ? Because if you are not, then using sender.tag is pointless.

Comment: @Nitish I am using the sender.tag and button is part of the uitableview

Answer (score 1):

You need check if the cell is not nil

```
guard let cell = matchedUsersTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? MultiUserTableViewCell {
   return 
}
// use the cell
```